# Where and when does CookieApplicationOptions LoginPath check to redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Specifically, my question is about the CookieApplicationOptions and the LoginPath. My project successfully uses Aspnetcore.identity to login and create a session cookie.

My assumption was that I would be redirected to my LoginPath once I log in and create the cookie, and before I ever log in and create the cookie, I would be directed to my AccessDeniedPath. Neither of these happens, so I'm wondering when these are call to be redirected.

Currently in my Startup.cs I have

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            //Connect DB
            services.AddDbContext<DollaWebContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DollaWebContext")));

            //Create Table
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DollaWebContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            //Configure options for user
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                //options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

                // Lockout settings
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;

                // User settings
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;



            });

           services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/register");
                options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/login");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/login");

                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "$DollaApi", Version = "v1" });
            });

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }
```

From research, it seems to have something to do with the [Authorize] tag in the controller but most examples don't give a concrete reason why.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie`, it will be used in [CookieAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/f2e6e6ff334176540ef0b3291122e359c2106d1a/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs).

For authentication process, it is achieved by `app.UseAuthorization();` which will call [AuthorizationMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/0a79d34f62a2e153d7104a88b487b75ef8860bb7/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs).

```
    if (authorizeResult.Challenged)
    {
    if (policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Any())
    {
            foreach (var scheme in policy.AuthenticationSchemes)
            {
            await context.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
            }
    }
    else
    {
            await context.ChallengeAsync();
    }

    return;
    }
    else if (authorizeResult.Forbidden)
    {
    if (policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Any())
    {
            foreach (var scheme in policy.AuthenticationSchemes)
            {
            await context.ForbidAsync(scheme);
            }
    }
    else
    {
            await context.ForbidAsync();
    }

    return;
    }
```

For `context.ChallengeAsync(scheme);`, it will call [AuthenticationService](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/be33a6f392b6182f253a930823003082ab5843c1/src/Http/Authentication.Core/src/AuthenticationService.cs).

```
    public virtual async Task ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        if (scheme == null)
        {
            var defaultChallengeScheme = await Schemes.GetDefaultChallengeSchemeAsync();
            scheme = defaultChallengeScheme?.Name;
            if (scheme == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).");
            }
        }

        var handler = await Handlers.GetHandlerAsync(context, scheme);
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw await CreateMissingHandlerException(scheme);
        }

        await handler.ChallengeAsync(properties);
    }
```

And above code will call `CookieAuthenticationHandler`.